# Here I send a message to controller this is working fine in Internet explorer but not working chrome why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

If anybody knows that question, post your answer here.

```
if (_Division == '') 
{
    window.location = "@Url.Action("Index", new { Message = "Enter division", @Result = 0 })";
    return;
}
```

Comment: Can you show exactly what error message you are receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try document.location instead of window.location

```
 document.location = "@Url.Action("Index", new { Message = "Enter division", @Result = 0 })";
```